# How to estimate needed spindle power for lathe/mill?

Tags: materials, torque, power, machining

I'm trying to understand how much spindle power is needed for machining various kinds of metal. I assume that as depth of cut and surface speed go up that it will cause the required spindle power to up as well. Additionally this will likely change quite a bit from material to material. I was hoping to find a table somewhere that gave this information, of perhaps gave me torque/force required so that I could calculate power for a given setup.

Is there some kind of table like that around? I might be missing the right search terms but I just can't seem to find something that would help me here.

Comment: Ah after some digging I found this. I'll have to look for these terms in the machinist handbook

Comment: Check out Joule and the measurements made boring canon barrels.